# What's the return type of a dynamic import?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.4

I have a file, which ***must*** be loaded asynchronously, so I made a function, which loads this file and returns the `Promise`:

```
export function load() {
    // ...
    return import(filename);
}
```

What is the return type of this Function? `Promise<any>` works, but it feels very weird. I'd like to write the signature as.

```
export function load() -> Promise<???>;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to use an import type and TypeScript [2.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html) or higher. Here is an example:

#### my_module.ts

```
export const user = { name: "John", age: 30 };
export const event = { name: "Birthday", date: new Date(1989, 13, 2) };
```

#### demo.ts

```
type ModuleType = typeof import("./my_module"); // This is the import type!

export function load(): Promise<ModuleType> {
    // ...
    return import("./my_module");
}

(async () => {
    const module = await load();
    console.log(module.user.age); // It works!
})();
```

#### tsconfig.json (Added for reference)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ], 
    "strict": true,  
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Will this not start loading the module in the first line? or is TypeScript smart enough to know that typeof import is to be ignored?

Answer (score 7):

With latest React, the dynamic import types are:

```
type DynamicImportType = () => Promise<{ default: React.ComponentType<any>; }>;
type LazyComponentType = React.LazyExoticComponent<React.ComponentType<any>>;

const dynamicImport: DynamicImportType = () => import('./MyComponent');
const LazyComponent: LazyComponentType = React.lazy(dynamicImport);
```

### Resources

- [`React.lazy`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)
- [dynamic imports](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import)
- Search for "`LazyExoticComponent`" in [the React types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/674a7033d617dff421b631e7acf7fd4f04bc8a5c/types/react/index.d.ts)

Comment: Not working for me. The line `const importPromise: DynamicImportType = () => import('./components/MyComponent');` is giving me such error: Property 'default' is missing in type 'typeof ... but required in type '{ default: ComponentType<any>; }'.ts(2322). Do You know how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

`counter.ts`:

```
export class Counter {}

export const list = ['test'];
```

`index.ts`:

```
type ImportClass<T, K extends keyof T> = T extends Record<K, infer S>
  ? S extends new (...args: any[]) => infer R
    ? R
    : never
  : never;

type ImportType<T, K extends keyof T> = T extends Record<K, infer R>
  ? R
  : never;

type Counter = ImportClass<typeof import('./counter'), 'Counter'>;

type List = ImportType<typeof import('./counter'), 'list'>;
```

Answer (score 3):

The type of import you want to consume can be defined for both default and named exports.

#### For Default Exports

```ts
// File with export - default-exporter.ts
export default {
  value: 451,
};

// File with import - index.ts
type DefaultImport = Promise<{ default: { value: number } }>;

const defaultImport: DefaultImport = import("./default-exporter");
```

#### For Named Exports

```ts
// File with export - named-exporter.ts
export const namedExport = {
  value: 451,
};

// File with import - index.ts
type NamedImport = Promise<{ namedExport: { value: number } }>;

const namedImport: NamedImport = import("./named-exporter");
```

---

*NB Mostly these answers include the `typeof` operator in typescript which great for knowing what your importing but can't limit what you import.*

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was able to just import as usual just the types, and dynamically import the actual classes etc I used.

For example,
I have a `HttpModule.ts` which uses `import { ... } from "uWebSockets.js"`
Even though it's in my internal library, I wasn't actually using the `HttpModule.ts` *(but my library included it in the `index.ts`)* I still got errors of the binaries `uWebSockets.js` where using is missing, in other words it's loaded the module.

This is because I had:

```
import uWS, {
    HttpRequest as uWSHttpRequest,
    HttpResponse as uWSHttpResponse,
    RecognizedString,
    us_socket_context_t
} from "uWebSockets.js";
```

Changing to just including the types:

```
import {
    HttpRequest as uWSHttpRequest,
    HttpResponse as uWSHttpResponse,
    RecognizedString,
    us_socket_context_t
} from "uWebSockets.js";
```

Skipped the file, when to initialize the actual `uWS` I did:

```
const app = (await import("uWebSockets.js")).App({});
```

Now, only when I'm actually using the `HttpModule.ts` it will import the `uWebSockets.js` module.